# Why does string replace of cmake have this behavior?

Tags: cmake

CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

SET(CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PAHTS on)

SET(CXX_FLAGS
  -Wall
  -Wextra
  -O2
  -std=c++11
  )
STRING(REPLACE ";" " " CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CXX_FLAGS}")

MESSAGE(STATUS ${CXX_FLAGS})
MESSAGE(STATUS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

And the output is:

```
-- -Wall-Wextra-O2-std=c++11
-- -Wall -Wextra -O2 -std=c++11
```

So I'm curious that why the parameter after REPLACE is ";"? Since there are no ";" in the input string. How does it works?

Comment: Have you tried to removed the "replace" statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon character is used as a separator for lists in the [CMake language](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html?highlight=semicolon#lists). The actual string fed to the string replace function looks like this:

```
STRING(REPLACE ";" " " CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall;-Wextra;-O2;-std=c++11")
```