# CMake string replace removes semi-colon

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a template cpp file that will contain several placeholders.
Excerpt:

```cpp
// WARNING! this file is autogenerated, do not edit manually
QString appName()
{
  return "APP_NAME_VALUE";
}
```

Cmake will read this file in, fill in the placeholders and write it back out to the shadow build directory for compilation

```
set(APP_NAME "real application name")

file(READ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/templates/app-info.cpp APP_INFO)
string(REPLACE "APP_NAME_VALUE" ${APP_NAME} APP_INFO ${APP_INFO})
# other tag replacements
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/app-info.cpp" ${APP_INFO})
```

But every time I run cmake, it seems to strip the semi-colon from the file contents.

```cpp
// WARNING! this file is autogenerated, do not edit manually
QString appName()
{
  return "real application name"
}
```

Is this expected behaviour?
What can I do to counter this?

Comment: The change from `//` to `/` reminds me of CMake interpreting `/` as a control character; countering that needed you to submit four slashes e.g. `////`

Personally I'd write a utility to replace the string and invoke that as a pre-build step

Comment: Why don't you use the [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295436/1607937

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Quite new to CMake (in process of migrating). I never knew this existed. Thanks for the pointer. Will look into this.

Comment: You will find your answer in https://discourse.cmake.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-and-replace-strings-in-a-file/1879

Comment: @Den-Jason the `/` vs '//' was a typo of mine. There's no problem there. Sorry for the confusion.
Re your link: Yup, that works. Your search skills are better than mine.

Comment: @Den-Jason I think that link is the correct answer to my question. Fancy turning it into a real answer here and I will accept?
(putting aside for a moment that I possibly should use `configure_file()` instead)

Comment: Already done; SO does not like "link to external websites" as answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://discourse.cmake.org/t/what-is-the-best-way-to-search-and-replace-strings-in-a-file/1879

> In my CMake script, I need to modify other source files by searching and replacing specified strings. In my case, the configure_file 2 command is not a solution because I have no control over the input file. Previously I used the file and string commands in the following way -

```
file(READ header.h FILE_CONTENTS)
string(REPLACE "old text" "new text" FILE_CONTENTS ${FILE_CONTENTS})
file(WRITE header.h ${FILE_CONTENTS})
```

> However this technique appears to strip out semi-colons from the input file.

Answer: **put quotes around ${FILE_CONTENTS} in both commands**

Explanation:

> It comes from a CMake’s list syntax, which is ;-separated, the fact that arguments passed to CMake commands are basically mashed together into a list, and that those commands take unbounded number of inputs. So you end up with one longer list.

> **Quoting prevents the semicolons in the expansion from being treated as list-element-separators.**

Consider:

```
WRITE;header.h;x;y;z
```

vs

```
WRITE;header.h;"x;y;z"
```

---

So in your case, it will appear as such:

```
set(APP_NAME "real application name")

file(READ ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/templates/app-info.cpp APP_INFO)
string(REPLACE "APP_NAME_VALUE" ${APP_NAME} APP_INFO "${APP_INFO}")
# other tag replacements
file(WRITE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/app-info.cpp" "${APP_INFO}")
```